# Detecting UITableViewAccessory in UI Automation Testing

Tags: javascript, xcode, swift, testing, automation

I have written a simple ToDo list in order to learn UI Automation but am having difficulty detecting checkmarks in my TableViewCells.

```
UIALogger.logMessage("adding a checkmark");

// get reference to a cell
var cell = tableView.cells()["Butter"];

// tap the cell (adds a checkmark)
cell.tap();

// make sure this is completed...
target.delay(2);

// view the child nodes
cell.logElementTree();
```

All I can see in the tree is a UIAStaticText, no reference to the `accessoryType` at all! How can I see if this is set to `Checkmark`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[cell setAccessibilityLabel:@"someLabel"];
```

Comment: You can also use appium GUI to inspect accessibility labels check it out:
http://appium.io/